# Disable all shortcut in NodeWebkit?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I currently working on a particularly sensitive desktop application, written with NodeWebkit.

It's appear that NW windows come with some default web-browser keyboard shortcut (like Backspace or F5). For safety reason, i cannot allow that.

Is there a way to disable ALL (including tab or enter) that shortcut ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

or a specific key

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
  if(e.keyCode === numKey || [...]){
     e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```